# how to display the first twenty lines for all the files inside a file

Tags: text-processing, files, find

I use this to put all names of the ".txt" files into a file:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | sort > txtfile
```

How to display all the first 20 lines (if less than 20, supplied with blank lines) for all the files that are listed in txtfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the filenames are newline separated in the file `txtfile`, you can read each file, check if the number of lines is equal to (or greater than 20), if so print the first 20 lines, else print newlines for the remaining lines:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r f; do 
    lines=$(wc -l <"$f")
    if (( lines < 20 )); then
        cat -- "$f" 
        for ((i=20; i>lines; i--)); do 
            echo
        done
    else 
        head -20 -- "$f"
    fi
done <txtfile
```

Comment: I removed my previous comment. But maybe simple concatenation will be faster? Simply create file containing 20 empty lines and do (head -qn 20 $file 20empty_lines.txt) | head -qn 20

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `awk` that supports the `ENDFILE` rule, you could do

```
xargs -a txtfile awk 'FNR <= 20 {print} ENDFILE {for (n=FNR+1;n<=20;n++) print ""}'
```

If you don't mind having a header for each file, you could use `pr` to print the first 20-line 'page' of each file

```
xargs -a txtfile pr +1:1 -l25
```

(Unfortunately although `pr` has an option to suppress the header, that option also suppresses the pagination). If you *do* mind the headers, then you could process the files individually and remove them using `tail` e.g.

```
while read -r f; do 
  pr +1:1 -l25 "$f" | tail -n +6
done < txtfile
```

or (with GNU sed's 'n skip m' addressing)

```
xargs -a txtfile pr +1:1 -l25 | sed '1~25,+4d'
```